# how definition geometry_msgs/Pose for link?

Tags: ros, pose, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi . i want to plot position x of /my_robot/pose topic, which is a type of geometry_msgs/Pose message. This can be plotted by /your_robot/pose/position/x.
in [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_plot) say :

step one -- >> geometry_msgs/Pose contains a member position. Look into its definition by clicking the link at geometry_msgs/Point in the api page.
step two -->> You see x as a member of geometry_msgs/Point.

how can i doing step one ?? where is a api page ??
how can i write geometry_msgs/Poin for links ?? i want ploot pose of link in rqt like this : /your_robot/pose/position/x

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256207/how-definition-geometry_msgs/pose-for-link-??/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2017-03-06

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[`geometry_msgs/Pose` API](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html) page. You'll have to follow the `geometry_msgs/Point` link.

This wasn't difficult to find. 2nd link when googling `ros geometry_msgs api`. Here, [LMGTFY](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ros+geometry_msgs+api).

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2017-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-03-06**:
thanks . how can i write geometry_msgs/Poin for links ?? i want ploot pose of link in rqt like this :
/your_robot/pose/position/x